# Cassandra connection issue during compaction

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, spring-data-cassandra

As soon as cassandra starts a compaction on one of the nodes, we see our application is not able to connect to that node. what i noticed is that when compaction starts in one of the nodes, that node CPU load becomes 100% and as the compaction progresses and cpu load becomes low, our application is able to connect back to cassandra.

We are running both our java application and cassandra on the same node using m3.xlarge Amazon EC2 instance. 
Both our application and cassandra has the following jvm settings -Xms2G -Xmx2G -Xmn512M. Cassandra has hardly 300MB of data, but still we see so many compaction happening. 
Here is how our one of cassandra column family settings looks like , we have around 20 column family with pretty much same settings. each column family has one secondary index.

```
bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='ROWS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  index_interval=128 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  default_time_to_live=0 AND
  speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND
  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
  compaction={'min_threshold': '6', 'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};
```

We are running cassandra community version 2.0.5 and data mapping library https://github.com/valchkou/cassandra-driver-mapping.

I looked around ,didn't see anyone facing this sort of issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Error Stacktrace**

```
2015-07-29 18:22:50.341 DEBUG 29056 --- [New I/O worker #5] com.datastax.driver.core.Connection 234 : [] [] [] Defuncting connection to /172.31.22.125:9042
com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/172.31.22.125:9042] Channel has been closed
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelClosed(Connection.java:636) [cassandra-driver-core-2.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:88) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneDecoder.handleUpstream(OneToOneDecoder.java:60) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.cleanup(FrameDecoder.java:493) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelClosed(FrameDecoder.java:371) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:88) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelClosed(Channels.java:468) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:375) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:93) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) [netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
2015-07-29 18:22:50.341 DEBUG 29056 --- [New I/O worker #5] com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster 1370 : [] [] [] Host /172.31.22.125:9042 is Suspected
2015-07-29 18:22:50.342 DEBUG 29056 --- [New I/O worker #5] com.datastax.driver.core.Connection 385 : [] [] [] [/172.31.22.125:9042-171] closing connection
2015-07-29 18:22:50.342 DEBUG 29056 --- [New I/O worker #5] com.datastax.driver.core.Connection 385 : [] [] [] [/172.31.22.125:9042-172] closing connection
2015-07-29 18:22:50.342 DEBUG 29056 --- [Cassandra Java Driver worker-36] com.datastax.driver.core.Connection 103 : [] [] [] [/172.31.22.125:9042-173] Error connecting to /172.31.22.125:9042 (Connection refused: /172.31.22.125:9042)
2015-07-29 18:22:50.342 DEBUG 29056 --- [New I/O worker #6] com.datastax.driver.core.Connection 385 : [] [] [] [/172.31.22.125:9042-173] closing connection
2015-07-29 18:22:50.343 DEBUG 29056 --- [New I/O boss #9] com.datastax.driver.core.Connection 608 : [] [] [] [/172.31.22.125:9042-173] connection error
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /172.31.22.125:9042
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.connect(NioClientBoss.java:150) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientBoss.java:105) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:79) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
2015-07-29 18:22:50.343 DEBUG 29056 --- [Cassandra Java Driver worker-36] com.datastax.driver.core.Connection 234 : [] [] [] Defuncting connection to /172.31.22.125:9042
com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/172.31.22.125:9042] Cannot connect
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:104) [cassandra-driver-core-2.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:445) [cassandra-driver-core-2.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager$4.runMayThrow(Cluster.java:1405) [cassandra-driver-core-2.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ExceptionCatchingRunnable.run(ExceptionCatchingRunnable.java:32) [cassandra-driver-core-2.1.0.jar!/:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /172.31.22.125:9042
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.connect(NioClientBoss.java:150) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientBoss.java:105) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.process(NioClientBoss.java:79) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42) ~[netty-3.9.0.Final.jar!/:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
2015-07-29 18:22:50.343 DEBUG 29056 --- [Cassandra Java Driver worker-36] com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster 1428 : [] [] [] Host /172.31.22.125:9042 is DOWN
2015-07-29 18:22:50.343 DEBUG 29056 --- [Cassandra Java Driver worker-36] c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection 592 : [] [] [] [Control connection] /172.31.22.125:9042 is down, currently connected to /172.31.27.168:9042
2015-07-29 18:22:50.343 DEBUG 29056 --- [Cassandra Java Driver worker-37] com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster 1428 : [] [] [] Host /172.31.22.125:9042 is DOWN
2015-07-29 18:22:50.344 DEBUG 29056 --- [Cassandra Java Driver worker-36] com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster 1473 : [] [] [] /172.31.22.125:9042 is down, scheduling connection retries
2015-07-29 18:22:50.344 DEBUG 29056 --- [Cassandra Java Driver worker-37] c.d.driver.core.ControlConnection 592 : [] [] [] [Control connection] /172.31.22.125:9042 is down, currently connected to /172.31.27.168:9042
2015-07-29 18:22:50.344 DEBUG 29056 --- [Cassandra Java Driver worker-36] c.d.d.core.AbstractReconnectionHandler 60 : [] [] [] First reconnection scheduled in 1000ms
2015-07-29 18:22:50.344 DEBUG 29056 --- [Cassandra Java Driver worker-37] com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster 1473 : [] [] [] /172.31.22.125:9042 is down, scheduling connection retries
2015-07-29 18:22:50.344 DEBUG 29056 --- [Cassandra Java Driver worker-37] c.d.d.core.AbstractReconnectionHandler 60 : [] [] [] First reconnection scheduled in 1000ms
2015-07-29 18:22:51.345 DEBUG 29056 --- [Reconnection-0] com.datastax.driver.core.Connection 103 : [] [] [] [/172.31.22.125:9042-174] Error connecting to /172.31.22.125:9042 (Connection refused: /172.31.22.125:9042)
2015-07-29 18:22:51.345 DEBUG 29056 --- [New I/O worker #7] com.datastax.driver.core.Connection 385 : [] [] [] [/172.31.22.125:9042-174] closing connection
2015-07-29 18:22:51.346 DEBUG 29056 --- [New I/O boss #9] com.datastax.driver.core.Connection 608 : [] [] [] [/172.31.22.125:9042-174] connection error
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /172.31.22.125:9042
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First make sure your system firewall is on or off .
2. Cassandra service is up or down .
3. put same jar version as cassandra and as well as cassandra-mapping jar .

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mahendra. System firewall is on , and we have enabled  the corresponding ports everything works fine until any compaction. the error shows up  as soon as one of the node starts a compaction.  i have the same version of cassandra and cassandra-mapping.jar .